# latest docker does not support using registries.conf anymore?

Tags: docker

Recently I installed the latest version of docker by using 'yum install docker': docker-1.13.1-103.git7f2769b.el7.centos.x86_64. I set [registries.insecure] in /etc/containers/registries.conf. Then I 'systemctl restart docker', but the configuration doesn't work. 'Insecure Registries:' in `docker info` doesn't contains my new insecure-registry. Even the file '/run/containers/registries.conf' didn't generate automatically.

I want to know:
1.Is there any problem with my configuration?
2.Or whether it no longer supports such configuration? Then where should I set my insecure-registries in latest docker version ?

I tried [yum update docker] and do the settings above on CentOS 7.6 and 7.8 server, but they are all like the above.

```
[root@centos containers]# cat /etc/containers/registries.conf 
# This is a system-wide configuration file used to
# keep track of registries for various container backends.
# It adheres to TOML format and does not support recursive
# lists of registries.

# The default location for this configuration file is /etc/containers/registries.conf.

# The only valid categories are: 'registries.search', 'registries.insecure', 
# and 'registries.block'.

[registries.search]
registries = ['xx.xx.xx.xx:1181', 'registry.access.redhat.com', 'docker.io', 'registry.fedoraproject.org', 'quay.io', 'registry.centos.org']

# If you need to access insecure registries, add the registry's fully-qualified name.
# An insecure registry is one that does not have a valid SSL certificate or only does HTTP.
[registries.insecure]
registries = ['xx.xx.xx.xx:1181']


# If you need to block pull access from a registry, uncomment the section below
# and add the registries fully-qualified name.
#
# Docker only
[registries.block]
registries = []

------------------------------
[root@centos containers]# docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-103.git7f2769b.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7f2769b/1.13.1
 Built:           Sun Sep 15 14:06:47 2019
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-103.git7f2769b.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.3
 Git commit:      7f2769b/1.13.1
 Built:           Sun Sep 15 14:06:47 2019
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false

------------------------------
[root@centos containers]# docker info
Containers: 10
 Running: 10
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 27
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: docker-runc runc
Default Runtime: docker-runc
Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current
containerd version:  (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
runc version: 9c3c5f853ebf0ffac0d087e94daef462133b69c7 (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
init version: fec3683b971d9c3ef73f284f176672c44b448662 (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 seccomp
  WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
  Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.7 GiB
Name: centos
ID: IQ5Z:3SPN:HWGK:3PX7:SB22:A6MG:IFAZ:MMCY:PUZL:FIVM:M3GH:KITJ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Registries: docker.io (secure)

------------------------------
[root@centos containers]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service 
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target
Wants=docker-storage-setup.service
Requires=docker-cleanup.timer

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=main
EnvironmentFile=-/run/containers/registries.conf
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-network
Environment=GOTRACEBACK=crash
Environment=DOCKER_HTTP_HOST_COMPAT=1
Environment=PATH=/usr/libexec/docker:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-current \
          --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current \
          --default-runtime=docker-runc \
          --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd \
          --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current \
          --init-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current \
          --seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json \
          $OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS \
          $ADD_REGISTRY \
          $BLOCK_REGISTRY \
          $INSECURE_REGISTRY \
          $REGISTRIES
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-abnormal
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

------------------------------
[root@centos containers]# ls /run/containers/registries.conf
ls: cannot access /run/containers/registries.conf: No such file or directory
```

Expected configuration take effect